# Identityserver4 - change the default 'AccessTokenLifetime' from 3600

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

in `Startup` class

where can i change the default Expiration time. (AccessTokenLifetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't control that in Startup.cs, instead you configure that per client in the client configuration.

```
var client = new Client()
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    ClientName = "My Client application",
    ClientUri = "https://www.tn-data.se",
    RequirePkce = true,

    AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
```

This allows different clients to have different token lifetimes.